# My java program is meant to complete the task as below, however I am unable to get the user input part working exactly

Tags: java

A run is a list of contiguous numbers that are either all increasing (ups) or all decreasing (downs). Up runs and down runs always alternate, and the last element of one run is the first of the next run.

Write a program that counts the number of runs in several lists of numbers. The first line of input contains the number of lists, followed by the lists, one per line.

Example

```
Input
3
4 1 8 12 17
2 5 9
-4 -5 -2 0 1 0

Output
2
1
3
```

Here is my almost complete code, which I need help with (the user input part, the logic for calculating runs is working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class test
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
{

    boolean prevgrad = false;

    int length;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many lists would you like to enter? ");
    length = input.nextInt();

    int[] number = new int[length];

    for(int y = 0; y < length; y++){
        System.out.println("Enter values for list " +(y+1));
        number[y] = input.nextInt();
    }

    int prevnum = number[0];
    int currnum = number[1];
    int totalrun = 1;

    if(currnum > prevnum){
        prevgrad = true;
    }



    for (int i = 0;  i < number.length - 1; i++) {
        prevnum = number[i];
        currnum = number[i+1];

        if (currnum > prevnum) {
            if(!prevgrad) {
                totalrun = totalrun + 1;
                prevgrad = true;
            }
        } else {
            if(prevgrad) {
                totalrun = totalrun + 1;
                prevgrad = false;
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Total run = " + totalrun);
}
}
```

Comment: Please include sample input, and the corresponding output for your program and explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: Your title is unhelpful and you don't explain what your code does that it shouldn't do.

Comment: My program is meant to ask the user how many lists they would like to enter. Let's say they type 5. Then it is meant to prompt "Enter values for list 1". It will then calculate the number of runs in list 1. It will then subsequently repeat that for lists 2,3,4 and 5.

Comment: If you see the sample input/output I have provided before my code. It says input: 3 (which means the user wants 3 lists). The first list contains '4, 1, 8, 12, 17'. There are 2 runs in this list, so the program outputs '2' as shown in the output section. It then repeats that for the other lists.

Comment: And my program isn't quite working in terms of the user input, but the logic to calculate 'runs' is working perfectly. I'm new to java.